# Add CSS to WebView

Tags: android, webview

Note that i'm reading the html file from  **res>raw>index.html(folder hierarchy)**  which also has **style.css** file.

But how do i add the css file... I'm not using the "file:///android_asset" path

Here is the code :

```
package com.veereshc.veer.vturesults;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView webView;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    context = this;
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);



        try {
           InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("index.html");
            int streamSize = stream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[streamSize];
            stream.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            String html = new String(buffer);
            webView.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.index), "text/html", "utf-8");

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID)
{
    InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try
    {
        i = raw.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            stream.write(i);
            i = raw.read();
        }
        raw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream.toString();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: got it working by adding internal css style

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline styles to your `index.html` file:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }

    h1 {
        color: red;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    ...
</style>
```

or you can create `styles.css`, include them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

and then use [WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.index), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```